# Custom query string in domino URL

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Need a way to pass a value between to pages using URL query strings if possible. However everytime I add "?customquery=customvalue" at the end it ends up to the 404 page of the website.

I want to basically make it look like this.
https://example.com/somedepartment/sample.nsf/page/hello+world?customquery=customvalue

hello+world is a document that is equivalent to a webpage.

I tried this plus a javascript that collects the strings after the number sign and it works.
https://example.com/somedepartment/sample.nsf/page/hello+world#customvalue

However, I couldn't use the hash sign because they told me not to use it and use another unique symbol instead. I am not aware of any symbols that could work the same with hash sign. If there is, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I was able to find an answer.

https://example.com/somedepartment/sample.nsf/page/hello+world?OpenDocument&RandomParam=sample

Now I could pass values by means of this format. Basically it has to be preceded by "OpenDocument" parameter before putting custom ones.

This documentation also helps: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Domino_URL_cheat_sheet/

Comment: Link only answers are strongly discourages because of link-rot. Please summarise the key points in your answer.